# How to make 'gdalUtils' package in R to use GDAL installed in OSGeo's directory instead of QGIS's directory

Tags: gdal, r, gdalutils

I have GDAL installed through QGIS and OSGeo in the directories:

```
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.6\bin\gdalinfo.exe
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdalinfo.exe
```

My `gdalUtils` package uses GDAL installed in QGIS and I want it to use GDAL in OSGeo because I have some troubles with QGIS's GDAL.

I set the GDAL path to OSGeo's GDAL using following code:

```
library(gdalUtils)
# following command forces 'gdalUtils' to use GDAL installed in OSGeo
gdal_setInstallation("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin", rescan = TRUE)
```

All troubles were gone but it was temporary. After quitting R session, when I restarted R, the same thing was all over again. How can I make `gdalUtils` package in R to permanently use GDAL installed in OSGeo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify your .Rprofile.

Easiest way is using package "usethis":

```r
library(usethis)
edit_r_profile()
```

This will open your current .Rprofile. You can then add a line to the file such as:

```
gdalUtils::gdal_setInstallation("C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin")
```

and save the file.

The `gdal_setInstallation` function should be then called automatically every time you start `R`.